# how do i remove the this "\r\n" in my string

Tags: php

I have problem in sending message to my client via socket,the string that I would like to send is like this "@@w32,12345678,xxx,5*zy\r\n"

```
$msg = $_POST['comm_input']; //"@@w32,12345678,xxx,5*zy\r\n"
```

if this is posted i get the value of $msg which is "@@w32,12345678,xxx,5*zy\r\n"

but my client will not accept this kind of message..but if I manually do like this without posting the comm_input;

```
$testmsg = "@@w32,12345678,xxx,5*zy\r\n";
```

It works fine,I tried to look at in firebug there is no double quotes and \r\n.and it works fine.

if I post the comm_input.and look at in the firebug there is double quotes and \r\n,how can I remove this.

Comment: Use str_replace for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `str_replace`, you need to escape the `\` with and extra `\`, hence, `\r` as string becomes `\\r`

```
$msg = $_POST['comm_input']; //"@@w32,12345678,xxx,5*zy\r\n" ;
$new_msg = str_replace("\\r\\n", "", $msg);
```

**Edit**: to remove double quotes

```
$new_msg = str_replace('"', "", $new_msg);
```

Consider reading this article : [Escape Sequence in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: the \r\n are removed now but how can i remove the double quotes ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_replace function` to remove \r\n.

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/184326)

```
<?php
$testmsg = "@@w32,12345678,xxx,5*zy\r\n";   <-- $_POST value
$order = "\r\n";
$replace = "";
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $testmsg);
echo $newstr;   //outputs @@w32,12345678,xxx,5*zy
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$msg = "@@w32,12345678,xxx,5*zy\r\n";
$str = rtrim($msg);
```

Refer [***`trim()`***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and [***`rtrim()`***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)